# AFTER INSERT trigger is not being executed (no notice printed, no table update executed) in PostgreSQL 12.5

Tags: postgresql, triggers, insert

I have created a table **transfer_task** and an after insert trigger **job_creator_insert**, that shall fire whenever an insert on the **transfer_task** table happens.
The trigger shall then raise a notice and insert a value into a secondary table called **logtable**. All actions are being run in DBeaver from the same database user in the same schema.

```
-- the insert trigger function and trigger
create or replace function job_creator_insert() 
returns trigger 
as $job_creator_insert$
begin
    RAISE NOTICE 'Trigger has been executed';  
    insert into logtable (status) values ('Trigger has been executed.');
    return NEW;
end
$job_creator_insert$ language plpgsql;

create trigger job_creator_insert
after insert on transfer_task for each row 
execute procedure job_creator_insert();

-- Logtable
create table logtable (status character varying(2000));
```

However, after executing and commiting an insert on the transfer task table, the logtable is still empty and no notice is being shown in the console:

```
insert into transfer_task (id,transfer_id,status) values (1,2,2);
```

and then

```
select * from logtable;
```

--> empty logtable

Comment: [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f4e84e1c08b2f656f487e6ca83d5676d)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Very interesting, for me the trigger does not execute. I am running on Postgres RDS in AWS, maybe that is the difference

Comment: It works for me too...

Comment: Take a look at the Postgres log to see if there is any relevant information.